# qmplot error Error in unlist(.all_aesthetics[1:42]) : object '.all_aesthetics' not found

Tags: google-maps, ggmap

I'm trying to plot points on a map using ggmap, ggplot2 libraries.  I'm successful using get_map to prepare the map, then ggmap to plot it...although I'm only able to plot ~80 coordinate points before I get an error that I'm exceeding the google map api limit of 2048 chars.  Does this limit seem correct/expected?

moving on to try using qmplot & qmap commands to (hopefully) overcome this constraint.
I'm successful with the qmplot command; I'm using: 
`qmap("austin", zoom = 11, source="google", maptype = "roadmap", scale = 2)` to create the map.
NOT successful with qmap command.  I'm using:
'qmplot(coord$lon, coord$lat, data = coord)`
      coord is a df with lat/lon pairs.
      I get the error:  Error in unlist(.all_aesthetics[1:42]) : 
  object '.all_aesthetics' not found
          I haven't been able to find (google) anything about this error mode.

To proof myself, I try running example code from pg 47 & 48:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf, example top of page 47

`violent_crimes <- subset(crime,
        offense != "auto theft" &
        offense != "theft" &
        offense != "burglary"
                         )
       qmplot(lon, lat, data = violent_crimes, colour = offense,
       size = I(3.5), alpha = I(.6), legend = "topleft")`

preparing the violent crimes (using a built-in R dataset) command work fine.  qmplot command results in the same error message that I"m getting with my code.

Comment: Please review the formatting of your question. You can use backquotes to enclose `code`, that makes everything more readable and increases your chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that was addressed. See [here](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/81)

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
```